# Pass Application to singleton directly in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-context

I'm a beginner to Android development.

When making a singleton in the Application Context, here is my code.

I pass the application context to the instantiation

```
class Blah{
 companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: Blah? = null

        //Singleton
        fun getInstance(applicationContext: Context): Blah =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: Blah(applicationContext).also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
     }
}
```

Can I pass the application directly to the instantiation? Like so:

```
class Blah{
 companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: Blah? = null

        //Singleton
        fun getInstance(application: Application): Blah =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: Blah(application).also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
     }
}
```

Will this present memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application` is also a singleton. This doesn't cause a memory leak because there is only one instance of `Application` and when your app is running you have one and when your app isn't running there is nothing there, so go for it.